# Can we define a \newcommand that outputs text within a fixed width box?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, width

I am creating a document which has a fairly standard structure. So I have created two commands that help me format it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newcommand{\witem}[2]{{#1 #2}}
\newcommand{\ws}[2]{{#1\textsuperscript{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\witem{Jan 1}{OHP} \ws{20}{5,5} \ws{26}{5} \ws{32}{5,5,5} \\
\witem{Apr 9}{BP} \ws{20}{5,5} \ws{33}{5} \ws{46}{5,3,3}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to change the `\witem{Jan 1}{OHP}` that is outputting "Jan 1" "OHP", always outputs the two blocks as 2cm + 3cm? (I don't need to worry about line wrapping or anything like that.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\makebox`:

```
\newcommand{\witem}[2]{%
  \makebox[2cm][l]{#1}%
  \makebox[3cm][l]{#2}%
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\witem}[2]{%
  \makebox[2cm][l]{#1}%
  \makebox[3cm][l]{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\ws}[2]{{#1\textsuperscript{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\witem{Jan 1}{OHP} \ws{20}{5,5} \ws{26}{5} \ws{32}{5,5,5}

\witem{Apr 9}{BP} \ws{20}{5,5} \ws{33}{5} \ws{46}{5,3,3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `[l]` into `[r]` if you want right alignment in the allotted area or omit it if you want centering.

Comment: So many good answers. I am ticking this one purely because it is the simplest. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg deserved as much as usual:-)

Answer (score 3):

For example use a `\parbox` with has the relevant width.

The example shows the usage with two defined lengths for this, which can be changed easily for any other purpose of the `\witem` command.

Other possibility: Use a `tabularx` with `p` and `X` - columntype approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\newlength\firstboxwidth
\newlength\secondboxwidth

\setlength{\firstboxwidth}{2cm}
\setlength{\secondboxwidth}{3cm}

\newcommand{\witem}[2]{\parbox{\firstboxwidth}{#1}\parbox{\secondboxwidth}{#2}}

\newcommand{\wtabitem}[2]{{#1} & {#2} &}
\newcommand{\ws}[2]{{#1\textsuperscript{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\witem{\rule{\firstboxwidth}{0.5cm}}{\color{red}\rule{\secondboxwidth}{0.5cm}}

\witem{Jan 1}{OHP} \ws{20}{5,5} \ws{26}{5} \ws{32}{5,5,5} 

\witem{Apr 9}{BP} \ws{20}{5,5} \ws{33}{5} \ws{46}{5,3,3}


And now the tabularx approach: 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{\firstboxwidth}@{}p{\secondboxwidth}@{}XXX}

\wtabitem{Jan 1}{OHP} \ws{20}{5,5} & \ws{26}{5}& \ws{32}{5,5,5}  \tabularnewline

\wtabitem{Apr 9}{BP} \ws{20}{5,5} &\ws{33}{5}& \ws{46}{5,3,3} \tabularnewline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer the `tabularx` approach

Comment: For what looks like it might be a basic table of numbers, tabularx would certainly be logical. However, what I am ultimately trying to achieve is going to need more flexibility than can be done in a table. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jacob: You noticed that I have actually posted two solutions (in one file, however)?

Comment: For what its worth, I also like your answer, and upvoted you, and appreciate your time to make this response.

Answer (score 2):

possibly the most direct implementation of your request would be via \makebox1

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newcommand{\witem}[2]{{\makebox[2cm][l]{#1}\makebox[3cm][l]{#2}}}
\newcommand{\ws}[2]{{#1\textsuperscript{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\witem{Jan 1}{OHP} \ws{20}{5,5} \ws{26}{5} \ws{32}{5,5,5} \\
\witem{Apr 9}{BP} \ws{20}{5,5} \ws{33}{5} \ws{46}{5,3,3}

\end{document}
```